# GLSL passing indiced normals to shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, render, wavefront

I generated model (Suzie)  in blender and exported it to .obj file with normals. During loading mode to my app i noticed that numbers of vertices and normals are diffrent (2012 and 1967).

[image: Model details]

I try to implement simple cell shading. The problem is in passing normals to shader. For storing vertex data i use vectors from glm.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> face_indices;
std::vector<unsigned int> normal_indices;
std::vector<glm::vec3> geometry;
std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
```

**Result i've got so far**

[image: Wrong normals]

**Buffers Layout**

```
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &geometry[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NormalVBOID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VIndexVBOID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, face_indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &face_indices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**Rendering fragment**

```
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_QUADS);
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, face_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: And what exactly is question? No, seriously - it's not at all clear!

Comment: The problem is how i could deal with passing normals to glsl in proper way. I tryed to arrange them to match the order of vertex positions from face definitions. No success.

Comment: Okay, then in that case I'd have a look at this tutorial if I were you: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/

I realize it's doing more than you're trying to do, but the important point is that it deals with passing normals to the GLSL shaders.

The code for the whole series of tutorials is about 20MB and well worth a look, I reckon. Ideally, you(I) should have the code already as you follow the tutes. Hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure that the model exported correctly? Can you try with a cube, for example? And what is `normal_indices`?

Comment: The model is generated in blender and exported by builtin blender exporter so i see no reason to assume that model isn't correnct. `normal_indices` is leftover after experiments

Comment: I've the very same problem, I don't understand the proper way to send normals because they have different indices than vertices. Can someone point me to a resource where I can find detailed info or tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that had such wierd problem was that some normals were used more than once to preserve disk space so i had to rearrange them in a proper order. So the solution is pretty trival.

```
geometry.clear();
normals.clear();

geometry.resize(vv.size());
normals.resize(vv.size());

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < face_indices.size(); i++)
{
    int vi = face_indices[i];
    int ni = normal_indices[i];
    glm::vec3 v = vv [vi];
    glm::vec3 n = vn [ni];
    geometry[vi] = v ;
    normals[vi]  = n ;
    indices.push_back(vi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also keep in mind that using the smooth modifier in Blender before export will in some cases help ensure that you have 1 normal per vertex (you may or may not need to also set per-vert normal view instead of face-normal view...can't rem so you'll have to test). This is because by default, blender uses per-face normals. The smooth modifier ("w" hotkey menu)
will switch it to per-vertex norms. Then when you export, you export verts and norms as usual, and the number should match. It doesn't always, but this has worked for me in the past.
This could possibly mean less unnecessary juggling of your data during import.